# Most efficient method to combine pandas DataFrames which have the same column value

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, pandas, join

For example, I have two dataframe which contain some identical sample name with different feature data.

I want to compare how many samples existed in both dataframe.

#### data here

[df1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQQlRFSmR6Q1RoNXM/view?usp=sharing)
[df2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQa3JyOVJraHJQT0E/view?usp=sharing)

A dummy way to achieve this problem I have though about:

```
hit = 0
for i in range(0,len(df1),1):
    for j in range(0,len(df2),1):
        if df1.Sample_name.iloc[i] == df2.Sample_name.iloc[j]:
           hit+=1
```

I thouth this loop procedure may waste a lot of time.  Is there any simple technology to takcle with?

Beside, how to extract the subset of each dataframe with idential sample_name and connect their feature data together into a new dataframe.

I have tried pd.concat(df1, df2, keys = 'Sample_name')

Comment: Is it possible to share your data?

Comment: Combining two dfs on a shared column is called [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: Using `df1.Sample_name.isin(df2.Sample_name).sum()` should work efficiently.

Comment: Do you want the size of the intersection of rows or the total number of hits over the DataFrames? For example, should the frames `df1 = df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1]})` produce 3 or 9? If it is the latter case, I think you want Divakar's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to get `hit` value -

```
np.count_nonzero(df1.Sample_name.values[:,None] == df2.Sample_name.values)
```

Comment: Some preliminary testing is showing this to be much faster than `isin`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: how large are the columns you're testing it with?

Comment: @ajcr small. I imagine relative performance get's worse as they get larger, I just don't have enough energy at the moment to test it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You should join your table by the identifying column as `index` then use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` to apply your comparison between what are now column attributes.